# CSS vertical scroll max width

Tags: html, css, sass, scroll, less

I need your help!

The designer did that:
[image]

But I can't display the list like that !

I need to have a max width on my container!
How my horizontal list can be align on left side and not affected by the max width on the right side ? :'(

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a conundrum. I would use `position:absolute` to get out of the edge of container. If the container is `position:relative` you wouldn't be able to do that. Play around with the `width` of the cards container to see what fits your needs because you can't really snap it to the right side exactly, you'd need to overflow it (so make `body {overflow-x:hidden}`).

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.strip-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.strip-placeholder {
  height: 50px;
}

.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h2>hello world</h2>

    <div class="strip-right">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="strip-placeholder"></div>

    <p>
      other content 1
    </p>
    <p>
      other content 2
    </p>
    <p>
      other content 3
    </p>
    <p>
      other content 4
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```